# Maximum serial port speed in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, irq

I installed a brand new xr17v358 serial card, which claims 25Mbps maximum. (For some reason this was the only card I could find that didn't top out at 1950s speeds. I'll settle for 1970s speeds in this application). How fast should I expect it to run in Linux?

I successfully ran a 2.7Mbps loopback test on one port. Yes, I used Linux's silly "custom baud" code and double-checked the speed with an oscilloscope. I can also run two ports simultaneously at 1.0Mbps each. However, when I try having 2 ports at 2.0Mbps simultaneously, I get:

```
serial8250: too much work for irq103
```

And then all serial ports stop working altogether. Is this a bug/misconfiguration of the xr17v358 driver, or a bug/misconfiguration of Linux itself?

Others have researched the source of the above error message [and found](https://marc.info/?l=linux-arm-kernel&m=111334035324612) that this is either a hardware bug or the data is coming in too fast for the CPU. Since this computer has a fully working Gigabit Ethernet card on it (not to mention a 5GHz Skylake processor and 400Gb/s of memory bandwith) can I assume that the CPU will not have any problems with a 25Mbps trickle of serial data?

Comment: Gigabit ethernet makes frames of up to 9000 bytes. After how many bytes does your card cause an interrupt? The data rate isn't the problem: the flood of interrupts that interrupt working off the last interrupt is the problem.

Comment: Also, fun fact: there's good reasons you don't do  UARTs in multiple Megabit/second. There's a point at which your transceivers need to be smarter than what an UART does; this has nothing to do with "1970s tech", it has all to do with the physics of transmission lines. That's reason your gigabit ethernet, your PCIe, your USB, your HDMI, your SATA and your S/PDIF are **not** just UARTs. UART is simple, but physically unsuited for high speed transmission over anything longer than a couple cm.

Comment: @Marcus The xr17v358 claims to have a 256 byte buffer. So if it's running at 25Mbps it still has a lower interrupt rate than 1Gbps with a 9000 byte buffer. And a fraction of what a modern CPU supports. (As for electrical interface, that's separate from the UART choice. RS-485 allows a standard serial port to run at 10Mbps over 10m copper cable. So I can legitimately call 10Mbps serial ports "1990s" technology. RS232 is fine at 3Mbps up to 5 feet or so. That's more than "a couple cm". Of course this can be extended even further by adding electrical termination at the receiver, as I have done.)

Comment: @personal_cloud The difference between 1 Gbit/s Ethernet and running a UART at 2 Mbit/s is that the Ethernet link is designed to run at 1 Gbit/s, whereas RS-232 "is intended for bit rates lower than 20,000 bits per second." The Linux driver obviously has not been not written to handle the equivalent of putting a 1000 kW engine in a 1970s Datsun, and why should it? There's smarter technology now to handle higher speeds. Btw, some drivers for high speed Ethernet use polling in addition to interrupts to prevent choking on interrupts.

Comment: @personal_cloud to give you a perspective on that: once your network card is mostly utilizing the link, the Linux driver reconfigures it from "raise an interrupt every time you're done or every time you received a package" to something where the OS has to manually ask it for new packets (poll it), and interrupts are only raised if that doesn't happen within a defined time (if at all). Switching back to polling – that's *how* expensive interrupts are. Your 256 B buffer causes an interrupt every 95 µs at 2.7 Mb/s – a total CPU killer.

Comment: @personal_cloud now, for the kernel to be able to poll the card under heavy load, the card needs to support that, hardware-wise. It probably doesn't, exactly *because* on a simple serial link, there's no such things as "frames" of significant size, with clear start and end, dexcriptors with pointers to which you could put in an RX or TX ring buffer – and thus, the only option is to serve an interrupt every couple microseconds.

Comment: @personal_cloud to give you a bit of perspective on the technical challenges of doing 10 Mb/s UART over RS-485: uff. You *really* want your termination to be dimensioned really really well there (and you're wasting a lot of power with these high signalling levels, too). The problem with high-rate communications is that electrically, things start to look like multipath/frequency-selective environments: reflections at each end together different propagation speeds of different parts of the spectrum mean that the signal you get out looks drastically different than what you put in –

Comment: and not just like a dampened version of the input. RS485, RS232 and all the other "let's make this more robust with more energy per time" don't solve that, can't solve that. You increase the signalling power, which makes you more immune to noise, but it doesn't change the "shape" problem you have. So, 10 Mb/s UART-over-485 sounds like not the greatest idea – in fact, you'll find that automotive electronics, which transmit high-rate data in million of sold devices don't do things like that, as easy as they'd be.

Comment: @Marcus In theory it's inefficient, yes, but the speeds here are so low, and cables so short, that it doesn't really matter. I'm driving a 25ft cable with a 2.7Mbps signal at RS232 levels and it's 250mW. Big deal. I'm tired of this "USB can do XYZ so therefore you need USB". USB is extremely complicated, especially for cable lengths over 16 feet, and especially for embedded projects. Setting up a UART is like 3 lines of code. Setting up USB is a whole freaking software stack. Great for people with lots of free time.

Comment: @Johan You're right, I think Linux has some issue with niche protocols like RS232. Linux is great at really popular hardware, and sucks at DIY. Probably because it's not documented. I mean, any kind of driver with callbacks, PCIe, interrupts, etc., is all "skin in the game" secrets. So probably RS232-to-Ethernet adaptors is the way to go. Anything in Linux has to be bog standard hardware.

Comment: @personal_cloud not about inefficiency, about need for equalization. I said that! I didn't want to argue with you over communication technology, because, I think as someone who's got a degree in communications engineering, I might be going a bit fast here. Again, this has very little to do with Linux, but with the flood of interrupts you're necessarily causing. I can't blame you for thinking USB is complex – you're doing that yourself.

Comment: @Marcus. That is really cool that you are designing gigabit+ electrical interfaces. But equalization is way overkill at megabit speeds. For megabits we just need the basics: balance the transition times and terminate the line. This is a crawl, not a run.